# Simulate Navigation Panel "GoTo" using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am in trouble with a concern.
Using Microsoft Word 2013, in the Navigation Panel, when you click an hyperlink, Word goes to that link and set it exactly in the top of the "page screen view". I would like to do that using VBA. I have a code that works, except it does not set the desired hyperlink exactly in the top.

My code is:

```
Sub NextPoint(control As IRibbonControl)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do
   Selection.Next(Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1).Select
Loop Until Selection.Paragraphs.Style = "Título 3"
ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range, True
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: As a test, try scrolling to the end first, `ActiveWindow.VerticalPercentScrolled = 100'scroll page to the end`, before `ScrollIntoView`. (I think IIRC that it also makes a difference if the range is already in view.)

Comment: Thanks @AndyG for the quick reply. I did what you said. With your line of code added, the macro works better, because now the link appears exactly in the same position on screen (more or less in the middle), but not in the top as the Navigation Panel does. Any more clues?

Comment: Sorry, not sure at this point how I might approach this - probably others will contribute - other than suggesting to then *scroll up a little bit* ;)

Comment: Thank you @AndyG for your last tip (scroll up a little bit...). It solved my problem P-E-R-F-E-C-T-L-Y. Now my macro works exactly as navigation panel does. I am so happy!!! The code I added at the final was this: ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6. You are the man!!

Comment: Jolly good ;). I'm a pragmatist. As long as the effect is not jarring, I would be loath to expend the energy to *try* and get it to the top. Navigating to a main section from the Navigation Pane is different to navigating to a style, as main sections would typically start at the top of the page. Of course, there is also the inbuilt Styles Pane, Advanced Find (even an Object Browser) to navigate through styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of these heroes of StackOverflow, I now have a code that simulate the Microsoft Word Navigation Panel perfectly, at least with my 19 inches monitor.
Here is the code, that I hope it can help someone else:

```
Sub NextPoint(control As IRibbonControl)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Do
    Selection.Next(Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1).Select
  Loop Until Selection.Paragraphs.Style = "Heading 3"
  ActiveWindow.VerticalPercentScrolled = 100
  ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range, True
  ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
  Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be challenging to place the text at the top of the screen using VBA. But you get a fair solution by iterating with SmallScrolls. So you get the text position in the window and scroll until it gets closer to the position you want.

I would replace your `ScrollIntoView` with the following call `SelectionToTop()`

```
Sub SelectionToTop()
    Dim pLeft As Long
    Dim pTop As Long, loopTop As Long, windowTop As Long
    Dim pWidth As Long
    Dim pHeight As Long, windowHeight As Long
    Dim Direction As Integer

    windowHeight = PixelsToPoints(ActiveWindow.Height, True)
    ActiveWindow.GetPoint pLeft, windowTop, pWidth, pHeight, ActiveWindow
    ActiveWindow.GetPoint pLeft, pTop, pWidth, pHeight, Selection.Range

    'Direction, defines scroll direction -1 0 or 1
    Direction = Sgn((pTop + pHeight / 2) - (windowTop + pHeight))
    Do While Sgn((pTop + pHeight / 2) - (windowTop + pHeight)) = Direction And (loopTop <> pTop)
      ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Direction
      loopTop = pTop
      ActiveWindow.GetPoint pLeft, pTop, pWidth, pHeight, Selection.Range
    Loop
End Sub
```

You can also try to center the text in the screen with a small change in the formula from `(windowTop + pHeight)` to `(windowTop + windowHeight / 2)` as follows

```
Sub SelectionToCenter()
    Dim pLeft As Long
    Dim pTop As Long, loopTop As Long, windowTop As Long
    Dim pWidth As Long
    Dim pHeight As Long, windowHeight As Long
    Dim Direction As Integer

    windowHeight = PixelsToPoints(ActiveWindow.Height, True)
    ActiveWindow.GetPoint pLeft, windowTop, pWidth, pHeight, ActiveWindow
    ActiveWindow.GetPoint pLeft, pTop, pWidth, pHeight, Selection.Range

    'Direction, defines scroll direction -1 0 or 1
    Direction = Sgn((pTop + pHeight / 2) - (windowTop + windowHeight / 2))
    Do While Sgn((pTop + pHeight / 2) - (windowTop + windowHeight / 2)) = Direction And (loopTop <> pTop)
      ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Direction
      loopTop = pTop
      ActiveWindow.GetPoint pLeft, pTop, pWidth, pHeight, Selection.Range
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Dr. Yunke for posting those interesting macros. I will check it out too!!